# Native app video

Tags: ios, video, cordova, vimeo

Does anyone know how to initialize the native video player for IOS. Currently I'm working on a phonegap application that needs this kind of integration. Whenever I link to a vimeo video it just pulls up safari. I need it to open up the native ios video player. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Use **MPMoviePlayerViewController** along with an **NSURL**.
That NSURL is init with an NSString that contains the URL string.